# I am not able to execute a code in C | Some sort of error that doesn't show up

Tags: c

My code is extremely similar to another I found online basically it doesn't even let me scanf the 2nd line.There are no error messages while compiling but it doesn't let me `scanf member type`.
Pls, spot my mistake as I am not able to.

**My code (Doesn't work)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char dept, member_type;

    printf ("\nEnter Department(C/M/A) : \n");
    scanf ("%c" ,&dept);
    
    printf ("\nEnter Member Type (F/S) : \n");
    scanf ("%c" ,&member_type);
    
    printf("works0");
    if(member_type=='S')
    {
        printf("works1");
    }
    if(member_type=='F')
    {
        printf("works2");
    }
    
    printf ("Department (C/M/A) \t : %c \n" ,dept);
    printf ("Member Type (F/S) \t : %c \n" ,member_type);
    
}
```

**Code I found online (This one works)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char fever, cough; /*Sets the chars.*/

    printf("Are you running a fever? (y/n)\n"); /*Asks if they have a fever and saves their input.*/
    scanf("%c",&fever);

    printf("Do you have a runny nose/cough? (y/n)\n"); /*Asks if they have a cough and saves their input.*/
    scanf(" %c",&cough);

    printf("Please verify the folling information.\nFever: %c \nRunny nose/cough: %c \n",fever,cough); /*Asks if the following info is correct.*/


    if ((fever=='y') && (cough=='y'))
    printf("Your recommendation is to see a doctor.");

    else if ((fever=='n') && (cough=='y'))
    printf("Your recommendation is to get some rest.");

    else if ((fever=='y') && (cough=='n'))
    printf("Your recommendation is to see a doctor.");

    else
    printf("Your are healthy.");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if `member_type` ends up with value `\n`?  What would your code do then?  How would `member_type` possibly end up as `\n`?   Answer these questions, and I'll think you will have your solution!

Comment: The difference is a single space character `" %c"` versus `"%c"`.

Comment: Lack of error messages from the compiler does not mean your code is error free.  The compiler can only detect syntax errors and will warn of some suspect semantic issues, but generally few semantic errors (valid code syntax  that nonetheless does not do what the author intended) can be detected by the compiler, in other contexts the same code may be entirely valid.  You should not regard successful compilation as evidence of bug-free code. `scanf()` is particularly problematic because it has complex semantics that are independent of of the language.

Comment: In the working version the format string for the second input is `" %c"`. The space before the format specifier requires that there is whitespace to consume in the buffer before assigning using `%c`.  The `\n` from the previous input _is_ whitespace so is consumed and discarded rather then being assigned by the `%c` format specifier.  Not perhaps the best way to deal with the issue, but that is why it works.

Comment: Thank you the space in front of "%c" worked!!!